# Copy file content using commons apache API

Tags: java, file, arrays, apache-commons

The file I am reading contains the following string: "werwererwerwerer"

I would like to do is read the file and write its content to a different file. I don't want to use a different API. This is just a step towards something else.

```
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("input.txt"));

FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile("output.txt", data);
```

The contents of the output file is: "��������erer"

Why and how do i fix this.

Comment: Why not just use FileUtils.copyFile?

Comment: Because i want to use an encryption I created inbetween. I just need to know that these two functions work.

Comment: Can you show us an hex dump of the input file (`od` might help under linux)?

Comment: How do i do a hex dump?

Comment: What are you doing with `byte[] data` between the call of  `readFileToByteArray` and the call of `writeByteArrayToFile`? Can you show us the code? I think you're converting the byte array into a String at some point in your code, and you're using the wrong encoding